# external css sheet to override default Vuetify component style

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am working on a project, which is built on Vue, Vuetify and TypeScript as its language, and my organization decides not to use the default theme which Vuetify provides, instead of with some custom theme, Is there any way to use custom theme, I tried adding a theme.js file and added a few colour and font changes but when I tried styling the vuetify components its not working. Any suggessions

Comment: You can find a list of the stylus variables [here](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/stylus/settings/_variables.styl).

Answer (score 0):

Vuetify has built-in support for `css-loader`, so you can `import * from 'css-library'` (or whatever you're trying to import).

Vuetify-specific (a-la-carte) components each have intuitive classes which you can modify in `<style>` or imported css, for example:

```
<template>
  <v-btn></v-btn>
</template>

<style>
  .v-btn {
    padding: 0;
  }
</style>
```